# Mongoid and querying for embedded locations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have a model along the lines of:

```
class City
    include Mongoid::Document
    field :name  
    embeds_many :stores

    index [["stores.location", Mongoid::GEO2D]]
end

class Store
    include Mongoid::Document
    field :name
    field :location, :type => Array
    embedded_in :cities, :inverse_of => :stores
end
```

Then I tried calling something like `City.stores.near(@location)`.

I want to query the `City` collection to return all cities that have at least 1 `Store` in a nearby location. How should I set up the index? What would be the fastest call?

I read the Mongoid documentation with using `index [[:location, Mongo::GEO2D]]` but I am not sure how this applies to an embedded document, or how to only fetch the `City` and not all the `Stop` documents.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mike,

The feature you are requesting is called multi-location documents. It is not supported in  the current stable release 1.8.2. This is available  only from  version 1.9.1.

And Querying is straightforward when use mongoid, its like this

```
   City.near("stores.location" =>  @location)
```

And be careful when using near queries in multi-location documents, because the same document may be returned multiple times, since $near queries return ordered results by distance. You can read more about this [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing#GeospatialIndexing-MultilocationDocuments).

Use $within query instead to get the correct results

Same query written using $within and $centerSphere

```
EARTH_RADIUS = 6371
distance = 5
City.where("stores.location" => {"$within" => {"$centerSphere" => [@location, (distance.fdiv EARTH_RADIUS)]}})
```

Comment: Would querying a collection of `Stores` and referencing the `Cities` be faster?

Comment: @Mike A, you dont have to worry about that. its going to be same.